# How to plot a dictionary in Python into a 3D plot?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I have a dict whose values can be accessed by the form `d[k][i]` (It's a dict `d` containing 25 smaller dicts `d[k]`, which themselves contain 25 values `d[k][i]`). I don't know how to turn these into a 3d plot, where the keys `i, k` are the x, y axes, and z is the value of `d[k][i]`. Can someone show me how to plot this into a 3D plot, preferably a surface plot please? Thank you!

[Here's the data of 'd[k][i]' I have.](https://pastebin.com/R69rxq1e)

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib is ok I guess, here's the link:https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html